# Create variables in queries

Tags: sql

I have to write queries for several tables as below:

it_mytable, de_mytable, us_mytable, jp_mytable

Is there a way to, instead of writing different queries for each of these tables, I can create one query and replace the first 3 characters when I need to use the other tables?

Hope I was clear

Thanks

Comment: Why not normalize the design and have one single `mytable` with a `language` (or `country`) column? Alternatively, if that's deemed unacceptable or impossible for some reason (usually it's not, and is just borne out of laziness in the process that should create/fill these tables), creating a view to make such a table available virtually (`select 'it' as language, ... from it_mytable union all select 'de', ... from de_mytable...`) will obviate the need for repeating this logic in every individual query.

Comment: Listen to @JeroenMostert's advice, have one common table for all countries/languages. You can even create views as replacement for the old tables, if backward compatibility is needed for some reason. (I.e. `create view it_mytable as select * from mytable where country = 'it'`.)

Comment: You didn't specify which database brand you're using, but if you *must* have separate tables both SQL Server and Oracle support dynamic SQL using sp_execsql and EXEC respectively. Theoretically, you could use this approach and iterate the table names in a loop. Here's a link that might help illustrate the idea. https://www.sqlshack.com/introduction-to-sp_executesql-stored-procedure-with-examples/

Comment: Add tag for database platform used.

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1
, column2
, column3

from (
  select 'it_' as locale
  , column1
  , column2
  , column3
  from it_mytable
  
  union all
  select 'de_' as locale
  , column1
  , column2
  , column3
  from de_mytable
  
  union all
  select 'us_' as locale
  , column1
  , column2
  , column3
  from us_mytable
  
  union all
  select 'jp_' as locale
  , column1
  , column2
  , column3
  from jp_mytable
) q

where locale = 'it_'
  and <other filters>
```

Comment: That WHERE clause will only apply to the last SELECT line. Build a UNION query object and use it in subsequent queries just as would use normalized table should have to begin with, except cannot edit records.

Comment: you are correct.  I have updated the answer.